# How to incorporate drift back into my Sql Server Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, version-control, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

With the usual source control solutions, a programmer will update his code from the repository and then check in his changes to the repository.

The only way I know how to incorporate drift back into my project would be to use the Schema Compare feature, however this feature just tells me what the differences between my project and the target db are without giving any indication as to what changes originated where so I could potentially revert changes I've made on my end if I'm not careful to exclude those items when updating my project using Schema Compare.

Is there a better way to incorporate drift back into my project without having to worry about being very careful not to blow away changes I've made?

Comment: What do you mean by "drift," exactly?  Do you mean fields added to a SQL Server database by other developers?  They can't delete or rename fields, otherwise they will break everyone else's builds.  Seems to me like they would need to include SQL scripts with their code revisions, if they are making database changes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but more specifically in my case by other developers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm thinking about situations where some refactoring may be needed on the database.  Projects I've worked on in the past have typically required breaking changes as some point or another, but when that happens we obviously have to be careful to make the code updates simultaneously and developers have to be careful to update code and db changes at the same time.

Comment: Historically, the way this has worked on projects I've worked on is that there is a "database update" step in the installation of the software that adds new fields (and sometimes deletes or renames existing fields) in the user's installed database.  Making an automated backup of the database is always a good first step.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah that's what I've done too in previous projects, but I'm focused more on the process of distributing changes made by developers here before deployment ever even happens so installation of the software isn't exactly part of that process.

Comment: That is usually done with SQL scripts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed.  But I'm using a SQL Server Database Project, as mentioned, and the idea is that it should take care this stuff for me without me having to mess with scripts.

Comment: How might that happen without code?  Well, you could write a diff algorithm, but it seems to me like scripts would be easier; you can check them into your code repository and maintain version control.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://arcanecode.com/2012/08/28/sql-server-data-tools-in-visual-studio-2012schema-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSMS, you could try using SQL Source Control in conjunction with your database project. We've announced a beta build with this functionality working here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/0c763f98-c55a-44a7-9100-80a6d9223d04

This will distinguish between changes made on the database that have yet to be sync'ed down to the project, and changes that are in the project that need to be applied to the database. If this doesn't meet your needs, the SQL Source Control project team would love to hear from you!

Comment: Thanks David.  RedGate tools typically tend to be a little pricey for me as a single developer and I hate to commit myself to something without knowing the cost though.  You have any info on what the pricing of this product will be?

Answer (score 0):

sqlpackage.exe has an option to detect database drift (i.e. changes that have been made since a database was deployed):

[DriftReport Parameters.
A SqlPackage.exe report action creates an XML report of the changes that have been made to the registered database since it was last registered.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

It requires you to register the database when you deploy it, but I don't think that's a particularly big deal.

Hope that helps.

JT

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your database project (SSDT) as target, and the "drifted database" as source, and the "update" button will update your model just as easily.

In other words you can use the schema compare to import the changes into your SSDT project, then turn around and publish your schema (with those changes newly incorporated) back onto the database.